# Simple decipher program

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I was making a program as school work. It was meant to decipher (not sure what its called) text which has been moved along on the alphabet e.g. abc to bcd.

```
alpha = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

userInput = str(input("Enter text:   "))
key = 1
userInput = userInput.lower()
print(userInput)

def userText(userInput, alpha, key):
    translated = ""
    for x in (userInput):
        num = ord(alpha[x])
        num += key
    translated += chr(num)
    print(translated)

print(userText(userInput, alpha, key))
```

I got the error:

```
File "/Users/Andreasjensen/Documents/decipher.py", line 13, in userText
    num = ord(alpha[x])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I think it means that it can't count with alpha? not really sure, but was hoping to find out the problem.

Comment: Your statement `for x in (userInput):` runs the following code with `x` set to each *character* of the string. You can't use a character directly as an index into a list, you need to change it into a number first.

Comment: Try this: `for x in range(len(userInput)):`

Comment: your indentation is wrong when setting `translated`. it should be within the for loop.

Comment: Btw it's called [caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

Comment: passing `alpha` is unnecessary since you already pass `userInput` to the function. I think you want to take the `ord` of x?

Answer (score 0):

x is already a text character.  Instead, I think you want that first loop statement to be a simple transfer to an integer:

```
num = ord(x)
```

Note that this means that your **alpha** array is useless -- which it is.  The basic translation looks as you've made it, although you still need to wrap around the end of the alphabet.  Note that your loop can collapse:

```
for x in userInput:
    translated += chr(ord(x) + key)
```

... or simply use a list comprehension: you make a list of all the individual character translations, and then join that into a string:

```
translated = ''.join([chr(ord(x) + key) for x in userInput])
```

However, this still doesn't handle the wrap-around.  I assume that this is your next stage.